# Variable usage outside the function where they were extracted

Tags: php, function, variables, global

I have an array with associated keys that point to instantiated objects. For example:

```
$MyArray = array();
$MyArray['Object_A'] = new Object_A();
$MyArray['Object_B'] = new Object_B();
$MyArray['Object_C'] = new Object_C();
```

What I would like to do with this array is to extract it to variables as references to those objects.

```
extract($MyArray, EXTR_REFS);
```

The statement works and I am able to use those objects inside that array just as I would do `$Var = new Object();`.

```
$Object_A->SomeMethod();
```

However when I extract them in a function that I define they can no longer be used outside that function. They can be used inside the function like the example below but not outside.

```
function ExtractObj(&$Array)
{
    extract($Array, EXTR_REFS);

    $Object_A->SomeMethod(); // This works.
}
```

So I need a way to make the extracted variables from that function to be usable from outside the function.

```
function ExtractObj(&$Array)
{
    extract($Array, EXTR_REFS);
}

$Object_A->SomeMethod(); // Not working (Yet).
```

NOTE: I have tried to use `global`, `static` variable modifiers or methods and so on but everything gives me an error.

Comment: The simple answer is: "you cannot".  If you want the extracted values to be available globally, you must do so in a global scope, i.e. extract them outside any functions or classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Variables have *function scope*, so they are not available outside the function. Learn to pass variables into a function as parameters, `return` needed values from the function and live with the function scope, it will make your programs better and more maintainable than one big messy global scope.